# Use Ruby RegEx to identify phrase in sentence

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write a condition that evaluates to true if a string contains the phrase: "no row at position 0".

For example, let's assume the string is:

"Feed returned error status: There is no row at position 0."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to look for a fixed substring, just [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001178) will do:

```
"Feed returned error status: There is no row at position 0.".include?("no row at position 0")
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you don't need a regex. A simple [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001142) will do:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "Feed returned error status: There is no row at position 0."
=> "Feed returned error status: There is no row at position 0."
irb(main):002:0> a.index("no row at position 0")
=> 37
```

`index` will return `nil` if it didn't find the string:

```
irb(main):003:0> a.index("no row at position 0a")
=> nil
```